# User input to choose category then loop

Tags: python

From the program below after the user has typed either d or w. I would then like to set up a loop where the user can type s to try again or q to quit continuing with the category they have chosen. I have already started code for that but couldn't complete it.

```
enter = False
while not enter:
    user_choice = input('Enter d to guess the definition of a word or enter w to guess what word a definition describes: ')
    if user_choice == 'd':
        enter = True
        show_flashcard()
    elif user_choice == 'w':
        enter = True
        show_definition()
    else:
        print('You must either enter the letter "d" or "w" to continue.')
```

Comment: This works until I try to type either d or w for a second time.

Comment: Mr Geek this works until I try to type either d or w for a second time. Is this because the choice = input line doesn't have a instruction for what to do when 's' is pressed?

Comment: It will try again when any key other than `s` is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without an `enter` variable, you can use `break` to stop a loop's execution, and use `continue` to enter the next iteration of the loop without completely executing its code:

```
while True:
    user_choice = input('Enter d to guess the definition of a word or enter w to guess what word a definition describes: ')
    if user_choice == 'd':
        show_flashcard()
    elif user_choice == 'w':
        show_definition()
    else:
        print('You must either enter the letter "d" or "w" to continue.')
        continue
    choice = input('Enter [s] to try again or [q] to quit:')
    if choice == 'q':
        break
```